# How to Bind Application base URL according to the Request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, url, httpcontext

We are having an serious issue in our application,  we are binding Application base url like this

```
 public static readonly string ApplicationBaseUrl = "http://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + GetApplicationPath() + "/";

  public static string GetApplicationPath()
    {
        string applicationPath = "/";

        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            applicationPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
        }

        if (applicationPath == "/")
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            return applicationPath;
        }
    }
```

we are binding the Logo or other Image files using Application BaseURL  like below

Ex: ApplicationBaseUrl +"/Images/"+"Logo.png"

previously we have used our application only in Intranet (using local IP) so we dint face any issue all images are binding properly

Now we are using Public Ip to access the application over internet, Here we are facing the Issue

The issue  when we access application using Public IP Still the locos are binding with local IP ( i.e `http://192.168.1.93/WEBUI/Images/Logo.png` ) due to this loco is not binding so its showing blank space, Once we reset IIS and then requesting application using Public Ip its working Properly ,the binding is chaned (i.e `http://PublicIP/WEBUI/Images/Logo.png` )

so we can use our application only either Local IP Or Public, we could not use both Environment simultaneous

we could not predict, Plz any one help us to solve this issue

Thanks

Comment: Could you not use "~" - Google App Relative Paths, ASP.NET.

Comment: i need to use Relative path ?

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, I think there is no need to all these lines and whenever you wanna bound something to your application root path, you will need to use `Server.MapPath()` method supplying to it the telda sign **(~)** which should handle all these scenarios for you.

Quoted from the official documentation:

> Server.MapPath(): Specifies the relative or virtual path to map to a physical directory.
>   If Path starts with either a forward (/) or backward slash (), the
>   MapPath method returns a path as if Path were a full, virtual path. If
>   Path doesn't start with a slash, the MapPath method returns a path
>   relative to the directory of the .asp file being processed.

an example:
**handling logo path**

Instead of this line: `ApplicationBaseUrl +"/Images/"+"Logo.png"`

you will use the following: `Server.MapPath("~/Images/Logo.png");`

Please let me know if this has fixed your problem, thank you.

Comment: I tried this But still get same issue  <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Logo.png" SkinId="sknLogo" />

Answer (score 0):

have u tried that way sir?

```
<appSettings>
            <add key="livesite" value="http://192.168.1.93/WEBUI/"/>
 </appSettings>


 Image1.ImageUrl = System.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["livesite"] + "Images/Logo.png";
```

Comment: Yes sir, Previously we used this way to get Base URL that time itself we got the same issue after that only we have changed method what i have said in the question

Comment: But other images does not have any mapping , image url simply placed in Skin file like this <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/arrow.gif" SkinId="sknArrow" /> even we got same issue for those images also